# wcf self hosted service and wcf discovery across machines not working

Tags: wcf, ws-discovery

I've spent 3 hours looking for any samples and going through many articles. I am trying to get WCF adhoc discovery mechanism to work for a self hosted windows service. If I run the client on the same machine it works, but on a different machine it doesn't. Every tutorial/sample (conveniently) shows it on the same machine which works.

- I disabled firewall on both machines.
- If I directly use the end point in the client, it works. So, it's only service discovery that is not working.

Here is my server code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:12345/discovery/Myservice/", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()));
        Console.WriteLine(baseAddress);
        using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(SampleService.Service1), baseAddress))
        {
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(SampleService.IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(), string.Empty);
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());

            ServiceMetadataBehavior metaDataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            metaDataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(metaDataBehavior);

            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Press to terminate service.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Here is my client code:

```
static void InvokeService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nFinding Service ..");
        DiscoveryClientBindingElement discoveryClientBindingElement =
              new DiscoveryClientBindingElement();
        var Services =
             discoveryClientBindingElement.FindCriteria = new FindCriteria(typeof(ServiceReference1.IService1));

        discoveryClientBindingElement.DiscoveryEndpointProvider = new UdpDiscoveryEndpointProvider();

        // The service uses the BasicHttpBinding, so use that and insert the DiscoveryClientBindingElement at the 
        // top of the stack
        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(new BasicHttpBinding());
        binding.Elements.Insert(0, discoveryClientBindingElement);

        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client(binding, DiscoveryClientBindingElement.DiscoveryEndpointAddress);
        Console.WriteLine("Data = " + client.GetData(1));
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.